# How to check if UDP port is available in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, udp

Now I am developing an iPhone project.

I want to iterate UDP port from 5060 to 50xx

How can I check if specific port is already open or free to use?

Thanks~~

Comment: Try to bind it and see if you succeed?

Comment: Exactly. That's the best way.